# debug only a part of code in selenium script

Tags: eclipse, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I use eclipse as IDE and java for writing selenium wd scripts. some times I need to do a lot of debugging and the script runs from the start each time.This wastes a lot of time.

Is there any way to debug only a part of code without having the script to run from start?

Eclipse provides debugging facilities, but it doesn't help me with my problem.

any help would be appreciated

Comment: When you say your script, do you mean your entire test suite? If that's the case, break it down into more manageable sections.

Comment: Script means for example a workflow like buying a product online, this can have traversing multiple pages and elements to complete workflow. filling data from a external source, if something breaks, I need to run it from start.

Comment: Then by the sounds of it, you'd need to run the entire process until you reach the part you're trying to debug. If you need to complete steps A-D to be in a position to debug step E, I'm afraid you can't skip straight to E. Are you placing your breakpoint at the actual point that is broken? Rather than at the start?

Comment: Yes, I am placing breakpoint at the point that is broken. As per the example you have given, what if E is not dependent on A-D, is there a way   I can debug only at E? If login is also part of A-D.

Comment: If E is not dependent on A-D and yet A-D requires the user to login, I'd say that E is in fact dependent on those steps?

Comment: Yes, agreed E is dependent on those steps. what I relaized is driver(browser instance) is starting point for any test in selenium, we cannot bypass that. I was comparing with qtp where i can debug a specific piece of code.

Comment: Yes, one of the disadvantages of Selenium is that it can't take over an existing browser instance. In cases like this, I spend time trying things using JavaScript in the console and especially the Snippets window in the Chrome devtools. You might give that a try. Once I get the code working, I translate it to Java or C# depending on what I'm working on.